# ng-if - checking for null value

Tags: angularjs, if-statement

I have a loop that runs through a data set and determines the folder setup for a href. I have a ng-if for each of the options but I need to add a check to one of the ng-ifs. I need a way to check if a value is null. I have used something like:

```
 ng-if="!shortcut.SAM3Link"
```

The problem with this is that if a value in my database is not null but does not have a value it does not recognize the difference.  I need a way to specifically check for null rather than not having a value.

Basically I need a way to determine between a NULL value in my database and text/blank using a ng-if.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use the [Strict Equality Comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#strict_equality_using):

```
ng-if="shortcut.SAM3Link === null"
```

Comment: This worked but only with two equals. So shortcut.SAM3Link == null. Thank you. I have tried finding the opposite, so not null values, using ng-if="shortcut.SAM3Link !=== null" and ng-if="shortcut.SAM3Link !== null" without any luck. Any ideas?

Comment: @Miriam What did not work? Be aware, `undefined == null` is `true` while `undefined === null` is false. Also, the negation of `===` is `!==`, while the one of `==` is `!=`.

Comment: Using three equals did not filter out as I needed it to but using two equals did. Thanks for the explanation. I was able to use != for my second question and that worked as I needed it to. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ng-if - checking for null value of Array

1. `ng-if="shortcut.SAM3Link === null"`
2. `ng-if="shortcut.SAM3Link.length === 0"`